# Using sed to parse a stream from tty

Tags: linux, sed

I am reading data from the /dev/ttyUSB0 input using cat.  this is a stream of text that goes on forever.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The data looks like this with each line starting with 002 and ending with 003 (stx and etx).  So the text looks like this:

```
/002{"xxxx": 12, "yyyy": "sendRegistration", "zzzz": 1}/003/002{"xxxx": 13, "yyyy": "keepAlive", "zzzz": 1}/003.....
```

I want to use sed to change the lines to something like this:

```
/002{"xxxx": 12, "yyyy": "sendRegistration", "zzzz": 1}
/002{"xxxx": 13, "yyyy": "keepAlive", "zzzz": 1}
```

Where I replace the /003 with a newline.

But when I use sed statement like such I get no output:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | sed -e 's/\003/\n/g'
```

Comment: maybe you should be using, "stty -a -F" instead of "cat" ?

Comment: you need a backslash in your sed command: `sed 's/\/003/\n/g'`

Comment: For me works `sed "s/\x03/\n/g;" `

Comment: instead of `cat` you might also try `cat -A`

Comment: My sed statement is wrong, But this is not the reason I am not getting any output because if I change the line to   sed 's/keepAlive/XXXX/g' I still do not get any output to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed processes input line by line. It processes a line when it finishes receiving that line. And (notwithstanding locale) I'm not aware of a way to tell sed to use something other than a newline to denote the separation of lines.

My solution would be to switch to a different tool that supports the ability to use an alternate record separator. `awk` would seem to fit the bill.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\x03"} {print "> ",$0}' <<<$'one\003two\003three\003'
>  one
>  two
>  three
```

So I would think that a solution to get what you want might be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\x03"} 1' < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! Please feel free to click the checkmark on the left-hand side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your syntax is incorrect.
Youre using \003, backslash is used to display special characters.
 Try `\/003`

Your sed command should look like so:
  `sed 's/\/003/\n/g'`
If you would like you can replace `\` as the seperator, to avoid confusion:
  `sed 's@\/003@\n@g'`

Comment: You are right about sed.  But this is not the reason I am not getting any output because if I change the line to   sed 's/keepAlive/XXXX/g' I still do not get any output to the console.